# An Internal error occured error code 0x4 remote desktop connecting to google cloud Compute Engine VM

Tags: google-compute-engine, remote-desktop, rdp, windows-server-2016

When tyring to login to RDP the "old" remote dekstop connection gave "an internal error occured"

And the new modern UI remote dekstop from windows store with version 10.2.1810.0 gave: error code 0x4 remote desktop

It seems a colleage has been logged in with wierd screen size. How can I resolve this without rebooting the machine?

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution.
In the new GUI untick:
"Uppdatera fjärrsessionens upplösning vid storleksändring" in Swedish
Which translates to: Update the resolution of the remote session when resizing

[Update remote sessions resolution when size change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9oMXh.png)

Answer (score 1):

Actually, even moving the port off 3389 doesn't help (for long)

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\TerminalServer\WinStations\RDP-Tcp\PortNumber

if there is an open port allowing RDP they will find it eventually and you will need to implement one of the above programs noted by Daniel.  That was exactly my issue as well.  You can usually tell if the problem is intermittent since it's just luck to get by the constant pounding on the open port...

Answer (score 1):

If you have access as Administrator to the VM still and there is a Event ID 1057 - The Terminal Server has failed to create a new self signed certificate

Then review the ...\MachineKeys folder permission and moved it then restarted RDP service.

Credit goes here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/the_9z_by_chris_davis/event-id-1057-the-terminal-server-has-failed-to-create-a-new-self-signed-certificate

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was the graphic choice. No idea why but as I swap between the 4 options, only one works

[image]

I needed to set it to Highest Quality (32 bit)

However, I then restarted the server, and it no longer worked but True Colour (24 bit) did work! So, hopefully by toggling through each will get you through

Answer (score 0):

In my case the cause was AVG Firewall blocking some RDP connections. I had to configure AVG Remote Access Module to allow RDP connections from some known IP addresses.
Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score -2):

Looks like this error code pop up for many things... from screen resolution resize to colour depth to firewall and more... Which is quite odd. You have to check what is your specific case.

In my case, when I had problems with `error code 0x4`, it was related to unprotected RDP port.

In my case, it was caused by **open, unprotected, RDP port 3389**. As many would guess, this is a **highly targeted** port by bots. If your port is open to anyone in the internet, it's just **a matter of time** that your server or computer will be targeted.

The best solution would be to only allow connections from trusted IP addresses, the ones you use for connecting to your server.

Of course, that can't always be possible, so another solution would be something like the **fail2ban** utility used on many Linux servers.

The two solution I've found are [**EvlWatcher**](https://github.com/devnulli/EvlWatcher) which is free and open source, and [**IPBan**](https://github.com/DigitalRuby/IPBan) that have a free and open source version, but also a paid version.

You only need one of them, as they do the same thing. Do not install both. They will scan your logs and will temporary or permanently block any IP address with repeated fail connections. I suggest you always have your main IP address whitelisted, so you don't lock yourself out.

Best regards to you all.